# office addin Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync error 13004

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js

I'm building an office.js excel addin.

I have code to try to get the auth info:

```
Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function(result) {
  if (result.status === "succeeded") {
    // Use this token to call Web API
    var ssoToken = result.value;
  } else {
    if (result.error.code === 13003) {
      // SSO is not supported for domain user accounts, only
      // work or school (Office 365) or Microsoft Account IDs.
    } else {
      // Handle error
    }
  }
```

when doing this, I get back error 13004, with message "name = "Invalid application resource Url provided.""

my manifest contains:

```
 <WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>a02210cd-88ac-4af6-b6cf-ee79006731c1</Id>
      <Resource>api://localhost:8001/a02210cd-88ac-4af6-b6cf-ee79006731c1</Resource>
    </WebApplicationInfo>

  </VersionOverrides>
```

I have created an addin app registration on:
   https://portal.azure.com
that has that app id (I tried both 'native' type and 'web' type not being sure which applied to an office addin).

Comment: Make sure the `App ID URI` value from Azure AD App Registration exactly matches the value you provide for `Resource`. To check App ID URI.. go to Azure Portal > Azure AD > App Registrations > get to app registration for your Add-in >  Settings > Properties

Comment: In the Azure ID App Registration, I find no field where you said called "App ID URI". I DID find a field called "Application ID", and the ID above (in WebApplicaitonInfo) matches it exactly.@RohitSaigal

Comment: You should see it in properties blade.. here is a screenshot.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OozS1.png  make sure that value in `App ID URI` exactly matches the value in `<Resource>`

Comment: Thanks @RohitSaigal . Now I see why you have that App ID URI (and it could be related to my problem). You marked your application-type 'Web appAPI" and I selected "native app". That field you reference only appears when you select "Web app/API". Now - I'm not sure what an office js plugin is. I don't know if MSFT calls that web app or native? Its really NEITHER (or a little of both). Its a javascript app, running inside native Excel code. I dont know what Native could mean? The closest for office addins would be VSTO addins, but they dont support VSTO with ADAL, so it cannot be that.

Comment: Anyhow - even after trying to call it a web app/API, it still didn't work. The format of that field is https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/d1df84dddd-5ddd-4f15-9f1b-bd56b221cbad, but the docs for WebApplicationInfo say the resource has to be of the form api://myDomain.com/12345678-abcd-1234-efab-123456789abc, so your hint doesn't appear to fit.

Comment: you just need to replace the `https:` with `api:` rest of the value should be exactly same. I am referring to this guidance on github.. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins.md#13004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several people pointed out correctly that the WebApplicationInfo.Resource must match the appId registered in your AD server.

But essentially ALL of my problems had todo with WHICH AD account to login to (I have a personal account and a corporate account, and you use a different portal to access each), and how to setup the manifest on that AD account/application registration on https://portal.azure.com.

There are hundreds of knobs/variables to adjust, and virtually no feedback as to what they mean, or how to adjust them. So I will simply present a WORKING example someone else could use to get this working. I'm not really sure just which knobs/permissions matter.

Here is a working (subset of my application) manifest:

```
 ...
 <WebApplicationInfo>
  <Id>fc63fe86-d03c-4ae9-b520-373fcb386d40</Id>
  <Resource>api://localhost:8001/09c94a00-cad9-4af6-ac2c-cdb81a724f16</Resource>
  <Scopes>
  <Scope>Files.Read.All</Scope>
    <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
    <Scope>openid</Scope>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>
  </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

Note - the 'id' above doesn't appear to matter, but the guid in the Resource MUST match the appid in the app you register. And the rest of the appID must match how you connect to the plugin (for now I just use localhost).

Use the portal https://portal.azure.com to create your app registration:

> select "Azure Active Directory"
>   select "App Registrations"
>   Create new App registration
>      ... most of the details probably dont matter because you will replace them all, but I selected type=web

Then use you will want to download your manifest and DIFF it against this one, and keep making changes to your manifest until it matches this one (because of the use of GUIDs in the manifest you cannot simply replace).

```
{
"id": "1a225d9a-13f5-4ff6-a62d-bdbd819ef5e5",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"allowPublicClient": null,
"appId": "09c94a00-cad9-4af6-ac2c-cdb81a724f16",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2019-03-11T15:45:24Z",
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [
    "api://localhost:8001/09c94a00-cad9-4af6-ac2c-cdb81a724f16"
],
"informationalUrls": {
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
},
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "StackOverflowTest",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2Permissions": [
    {
        "adminConsentDescription": "consent to use plugin",
        "adminConsentDisplayName": "consent to use plugin",
        "id": "56b9c899-4e7f-47d3-a584-50ab695b164e",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "type": "User",
        "userConsentDescription": "consent to use plugin",
        "userConsentDisplayName": null,
        "value": "user_impersonation"
    }
],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [
    {
        "appId": "57fb890c-0dab-4253-a5e0-7188c88b2bb4",
        "permissionIds": [
            "56b9c899-4e7f-47d3-a584-50ab695b164e"
        ]
    },
    {
        "appId": "d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c",
        "permissionIds": [
            "56b9c899-4e7f-47d3-a584-50ab695b164e"
        ]
    },
    {
        "appId": "bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3",
        "permissionIds": [
            "56b9c899-4e7f-47d3-a584-50ab695b164e"
        ]
    }
],
"publisherDomain": "USENAMEFROMYOURDEFAULTGENERATEDAPPREGISRATION.onmicrosoft.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [
    {
        "url": "https://localhost:8001",
        "type": "Web"
    }
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
        "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {
                "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                "type": "Scope"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",
"tags": [],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
```

}

Note - you cannot just COPY the critical requiredResourceAccess and preAuthorizedApplications sections. Instead, use the GUI in the Ad app registration page, and go to the section "Expose an API". First add a scope with scope-name = 'user_impersonation'; And then add 3 Authorized client applications (assuming you want to support excel desktop and office online) - 57fb890c-0dab-4253-a5e0-7188c88b2bb4, d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c, bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3

That should produce sections in your manifest which are quite close to mine for preAuthorizedApplications.

And I'd like to give credit to the person who helped me figure all this out - Jim Barrett (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4114387/jim-barrett)

Best of luck!

Comment: Registering the app at portal.azure.com is not supported. You should use the AAD V2.0 endpoint. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins.

Comment: Try it yourself. I wish I could include a screenshot. I TRIED what you are suggesting. I created the app on the site the docs recommended. THen a dialog (on that site) popped up saying "We have a new experience in Azure Portal
We recommend managing this application in the Azure Portal." So then the last 99% of editing/fiddling with the app registration was done on the azure portal.
 @RickKirkham

Comment: @RickKirkham You may have misunderstood me earlier. I never said Rohit's advice was wrong. But i had followed those instructions ALREADY and my app wasn't working. It turned out it wasn't working NOT because of the stuff in those instructions (the manifest file etc) - but because of the detail (the instructions left out and which have/are changing) about how to configure the AD setup. Not saying EVERYONE will have my problem. Just that MY problem was NOT with the manifest for the addin, but with the AD setup/permissions.

Comment: Well, in a comment to my answer, you said, with regard to Rohit's answer "But the answer was WRONG ...".  I'm still not clear on whether you think the current documentation works. You say you had a problem with "the detail (the instructions left out and which have/are changing) about how to configure the AD setup". The instructions work for me and others. What is the detail left out?

Comment: @RickKirkham I'm going to have to phrase my comments more carefully. Sorry. It was WRONG in the sense that it did NOT answer my question, nor solve my problem. Not in the sense that it was false. So my wording then was 'wrong' ;-). What I should have said was just that it didn't correctly answer my question. It was not 'false'. In fact - it was little more than copying and pasting the original instructions. As for the second part of your question - about WHAT was wrong - I tried to answer that in MY provided answer (above). No room here to repeat. But focus on AD manifest part of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The **`error code 13004`** and the message **`Invalid application resource Url provided`** point out that there is a mismatch between the value being used to identify the resource in Azure AD v/s what is specified in the add-in manifest.

The value for **`<Resource>`** tag in your add-in manifest should exactly match the value in `App ID URI` for registration in Azure AD. Only difference will be that protocol part of resource value in your manifest will be **`api`** and not **`https`**.

So in case

- App ID URI in Azure AD app registration is **`https://yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com/GUID1`**
- Resource value will be **`api://yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com/GUID1`**

There may or may not be further issues that need to be resolved before add-in authentication works fine, so do look out if you start getting a different error message after doing these steps.

Here are some guidance links from Microsoft Docs and Github which explain this:

1. [Troubleshooting Error Messages for SSO in office add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins.md#13004)

   [image]
2. [Enable Single Sign-on for Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#configure-the-add-in)

   [image]

   [image]
3. [Register an Office Add-in that uses SSO with the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2)

   [image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this doesn't address my particular problem (it was with the AD configuration).

Comment: I have one very specific question: Does the web content of the Add-in need to be hosted on Azure in particular or can be hosted on any other hosting provider?

Answer (score 1):

Your problems stem from the fact that you are trying to register the add-in at portal.azure.com. ***This is not supported.*** To use the Single Sign-on system for Office add-ins, you must register at the AAD V 2.0 endpoint: [enter link description here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/). This is stated in the docs, for example, it is in the overview article: [Enable single sign-on in an add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins), which @RohitSaigal linked to, in a couple of places. He also linked to the instructions for how to do this at [Register and Office add-in that uses the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2).

The answer that you gave to your own question is not a supported configuration.

I think you should consider giving Rohit the bounty.

Comment: I would be happy to give anyone you wish the bounty ;-). But the answer was WRONG so I wont mark it as correct. And YOU are wrong about the registration - as I covered in teh response to the other comment. Docs on the web are often obsolete. The site you are referring REDIRECTS to the azure portal. And as I had to edit and change and fiddle with the app registration for a long time, I spent 99% of my time on the azure portal. I also CREATED fully functional app registrations on that app portal as well

Comment: @LewisPringle Thanks for the info. I'll look into this. This remark: "The site you are referring REDIRECTS to the azure portal." should have been in the original post. That it a crucial piece of information that readers of your post can't be assumed to know.

Comment: @LewisPringle When I go to the apps.dev.microsoft.com, it does not automatically redirect. It has a notice at the top reading "We will no longer support registering and managing converged and Azure AD applications here starting May 2019. We recommend that you manage your existing applications and register new applications by using the App registrations (Preview) experience in the Azure portal. Click this banner to launch the preview experience." But there is still an **Add an app** button and I can still register following the directions in the documentation. Is this what you see?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. Sorry - I realize I may have been misleading. I meant 'redirect' in the ENGLISH sense of the word, not the HTTP sense of the word. And more importantly, the gist of my point is that despite the older documentaiton, it DOES appear supported to use that portal.azure site (and soon will be the ONLY thing supported).

Comment: Thanks. I have created an internal work item for Microsoft to replace the current AAD registration instructions with instructions for the azure.portal experience before May. I don't know if the new instructions will match your answer to this question; but until May I recommend that people use the existing instructions, as per @RohitSaigal 's answer. At least until May, it is a CORRECT answer. Thanks for bringing this change to our attention.